# How to fix the code so that an additional card appears only for the country on which there was a click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I click on the line of one country, additional cards appear for the entire list of countries. How to make it so that an additional card opens only for the country on which there was a click?

````
    /*const countries = useCountry();*/
    const [showCard, setShowCard] = useState('none');

    const currentView = {
        display: showCard
    }

    const ShowOnClick = () =>{
        let display = 'flex'
        setShowCard(display)
    }       

    if(!data){
        return(
            <h1>Loading...</h1>
        )
    }

    return (
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>№</th>
                <th>Country</th>
                <th>Total Confirmed</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {data.map((country, index) => (
                <>
                <tr onClick={ShowOnClick} key={index}>
                    <td>{index + 1}</td>
                    <td>{country.Country}</td>
                    <td>{country.TotalConfirmed}</td>
                    {/*<td className="deaths">{country.TotalDeaths}</td>
                    <td>{country.TotalRecovered}</td>*/}
                </tr>
                 <div  className="card" style={currentView}>
                    <h4>{country.Country}</h4>
                </div>
                </>
            ))}
        </tbody>
    </table>
    )
};```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new component called TableRow and have the state inside it . So that each Row will have its own state .

```
const TableRow = ({ country, rowNo }) => {
  const [showCard, setShowCard] = useState('none');
 
  const ShowOnClick = () =>{
    setShowCard(display)
}   

  return (
    <>
    <tr onClick={ShowOnClick} key={index}>
        <td>{rowNo}</td>
        <td>{country.Country}</td>
        <td>{country.TotalConfirmed}</td>
        {/*<td className="deaths">{country.TotalDeaths}</td>
        <td>{country.TotalRecovered}</td>*/}
    </tr>
     <div  className="card" style={{ display: showCard}}>
        <h4>{country.Country}</h4>
    </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Now you can use it as

```
<tbody>
        {data.map((country, index) => (
           <TableRow key={index} country={country} rowNo={index + 1}  />
        ))}
</tbody>
```

The advantage of this approach is now click on a row will re-render only that row instead of all the others rows which will happen if your state was in the component which renders all the rows .

Comment: Thank you! It works, but with one mistake. Those cell <td>{index + 1}</td> shows NaN 
instead of a serial number.